# how to compile stm32f746g-discovery based chirp code in keil

Tags: chirp

I have to test stm32f746g-discovery based chirp code, but I need to do it within Keil.
I tried but its giving errors.
I have tried both arm cc 6 as well as GNU for arm, but still cant compile.
For arm cc, error is:
.\test2.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol chirp_sdk_error_code_to_string (referred from main.o).
.\test2.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol chirp_sdk_set_config (referred from main.o).
.\test2.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol new_chirp_sdk (referred from main.o).

These are the only functions called.

Can you please provide keil template for chirp?

Comment: Which Chirp C SDK version are you using?

Comment: ChirpSDK-C-3.3.1

Answer (score 3):

Damien from Chirp here,

Unfortunately we don't provide libraries for Keil or Arm CC. Our libraries for Cortex M micro controllers are built with the GNU Embedded Toolchain.

If you still want to test on the stm32f7, go to our [chirp-embedded-examples](https://github.com/chirp/chirp-embedded-examples) repo, clone and execute `make` in the `stm32f746g-discovery` folder. You can find more information in the `readme` in this same folder.

Comment: Okay I compiled it successfully in eclipse.

Comment: There have been some changes in my project.
I just came across chirp working on arduino version for nrf52840.
But I have to use nrf52840 as baremetal.
Is it possible to use chirp over nrf52840 baremetal?
Which architecture static library should i use?
and what additional features do I need to add to my project? (like: dsp,adc,fft etc...)
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So, nrf52840 is based on Arm Cortex M4 which means you can use our library for this type of micro controller (libchirp-sdk_none-armv7m-cm4[softfp/hard].a). You will need to put in place the audio layer which is done with ADC/DAC. We never had to do it on bare metal on this chip so I would advise to look at the Nordic docs, it seems they provide an SDK to do all of that :)